# Why is there runtime-error? I have already set long int

Tags: c++, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>

long equation(long x){
  return x*x+x;
}

long BinarySearch(long arr[],long start,long end,long k){

  if(start==0 && end==0){
    return 0;
  }
  else if((end-start)<=5){
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
      if(arr[i]<=k && arr[i+1]>k){
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    long mid=(start+end)/2;
    if(arr[mid]==k){
      return mid;
    }
    else if(arr[mid]>k){
      return BinarySearch(arr,start,mid-1,k);
    }
    else{
      return BinarySearch(arr,mid+1,end,k);
    }
  }

}

int main() {

  long a;
  scanf("%ld",&a);
  long roots[a];
  for(long i=0;i<a;i++){
    roots[i]=equation(i);
  }

  printf("%ld",BinarySearch(roots,0,a-1,a));

  return 0;
}
```

For small numbers (under 100000000), this code works, but over 100000000, this code has runtime error. I set every variables as a long int... I used c++ tutor, it said that the step at long equation has a problem. Invalid write of size 8... Why?

Comment: Since it needs to be said: `long roots[a];` is a variable length array and is not allowed by the C++ standard (although some compilers do support it). And in general, your code does not use any C++ feature whatsoever. You would not have the problem you are describing if you used `std::vector<long> roots(a);` instead.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but using a recursive algorithm is really the wrong approach here.

Comment: [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array "Variable-length array")s are not standard C++

Comment: `long equation(long x){ return x*x+x; }` will exhibit signed integer overflow (hence undefined behavior) for large enough number (and certainly for 100000000).

Comment: You don't say what your environment is, but debugging tools should really be a reflex. With gcc or clang, `-fsanitize=address -g` gives you a nice message that there is a stack overflow on line 38.

Answer (score 0):

> long roots[a];

It's *[variable length array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)*. Which is not a part of C++ standard. (But GNU compliers do support it. And it's a part of C99 and C11-*optional*). Not knowing how it implemented. But whatever it is, it cannot contain so many long ints.

lets do a mathematical problem. Assume `1MB = 10**6 Bytes`, a long int's size is 4 Bytes, then `100000000` longs takes 400MB memory. I don't think it can be stored in a stack which is typically 4MB.

And you said that *you' ve used long int*. But in most compliers, there's no difference between `int` and `long`(though it may be unrelated to this question).

And big enough data range makes you call the recursion function too many times, which may leads to *[stack overflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)*.

Comment: At most, there will be `1+log2(N)` recursive calls where `N` is the size of the range to search. But definitely, `long roots[a]` for really huge `a`s will break something.

Comment: @YSC Yes, I do think even a array in DSS or heap cannot contain so many elements.

Comment: 400M of memory is not much using the heap, current computers have gigabytes of memory, it is only a problem because the stack is more limited (typically less than 10M unless you ask for more explicitly).

Comment: @MarcGlisse I don't really know how does vla be stored, and a heap are typically 1GB, for I' ve never apply to such a big memory, even in algorithm competitions. I've got it, thanks :)

Comment: I'd appreciate a hint to cstdint header for the `[u]intN_t` data types. Number of recursions is not *necessarily* a problem, as is, the function would qualify for [tail call optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization)...